# Optional initializer, through preprocessor trickery?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know that this will not work, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do

```
#if ASSIGN_ALLOWED
    #define MAYBE_SKIP_REST_OF_LINE 
#else
    #define MAYBE_SKIP_REST_OF_LINE ; //
#endif

char str[80]  MAYBE_SKIP_REST_OF_LINE = "Hello\n";
long array[3] MAYBE_SKIP_REST_OF_LINE = { 7,8,9 };
int x         MAYBE_SKIP_REST_OF_LINE = 3;
//...many many more similar lines...
```

Is there a way to do this such that it works?

Comment: What type of problems would like to solve with that trick?

Comment: Sorry, too complicated to explain. But its part of a horrible hack on a very large, very old program. I'm not suggesting anyone copy me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure:

```
#ifdef ASSIGN_ALLOWED
    #define OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(x) = x 
#else
    #define OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(x) 
#endif

char str[80] OPTIONAL_INTIALISER("Hello\n");
#define ARRAY_INIT { 7,8,9 }
long array[3] OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(ARRAY_INIT);
#undef ARRAY_INIT
int x OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(3);
```

Any initialisers containing commas, like for `array` in the example, will need to be expanded from their own macro, like `ARRAY_INIT` in the above.  If your compiler supports C99 varargs macros, then you can instead do it in a cleaner way:

```
#ifdef ASSIGN_ALLOWED
    #define OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(...) = __VA_ARGS__ 
#else
    #define OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(...) 
#endif

char str[80] OPTIONAL_INTIALISER("Hello\n");
long array[3] OPTIONAL_INITIALISER({ 7,8,9 });
int x OPTIONAL_INITIALISER(3);
```

Comment: won't the commas in the 7,8,9 cause the preprocessor to think the macro has been given three arguments?

Comment: Mick: Ahh yes, altered to fix this.

Comment: __VA_ARGS__ now, that's better.

Comment: another suggestion: add the braces to the macro definition, ie `= { __VA_ARGS__ }` ; this works for scalar types as well: `int foo = { 4 };` is valid C

Answer (score -1):

As comments are filtered out in the preprocessor run, i dont think so

Answer (score -1):

It would depend on how the preprocessor worked with comments and macros. If it strips comments after macro expansion then your smooth sailing, but otherwise it might not work simply due to the preprocessor implementation.

You could try this? (it would be messy though).

```
#define MAYBE_SKIP(code) code
#define MAYBE_SKIP(code) /* code */
```

Comment: Comments are stripped before too early for that to work.  Maybe you should check before suggesting answers; it will avoid down-votes.  (No, it wasn't mine.)

Answer (score -1):

The preprocessor strips out commented sections. Try running

```
gcc -E source.c
```

This will run the preprocessor on your code but will not actually compile it, allowing you to see what happens after macro expansion. You should notice that all the comments are gone from any expanded macros.

Comment: Accurate observation - but no suggestion for how to achieve the desired result.